# Stack OverFlow Exception in Quicksort Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, exception, stack

I am having a problem with my quicksort algorithm when trying to sort relatively big list that has no duplicates and are almost sorted (with only 5 numbers to sort).

Below please find the code.

```
 public static void MyQuickSort(List<int> list, int left, int right)
    {
        if (list == null || list.Count <= 1)
            return;

        if (left < right)
        {
            int pivotIdx = MyPartition(list, left, right);
            //Console.WriteLine("MQS " + left + " " + right);
            //DumpList(list);
            MyQuickSort(list, left, pivotIdx - 1);
            MyQuickSort(list, pivotIdx, right);
        }
    }

static int MyPartition(List<int> list, int left, int right)
    {
        int start = left;
        int pivot = list[start];
        left++;
        right--;

        while (true)
        {
            while (left <= right && list[left] <= pivot)
                left++;

            while (left <= right && list[right] > pivot)
                right--;

            if (left > right)
            {
                list[start] = list[left - 1];
                list[left - 1] = pivot;

                return left;
            }


            int temp = list[left];
            list[left] = list[right];
            list[right] = temp;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you debug your code see what happens? On which line you get this exception?

Comment: Yes, it is happening while partitioning the list... Furthermore, it works perfectly when inputting a list with random numbers that include duplicates and and no values are in order.

Comment: Phil, the type of data will determine how many recursive calls are made.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive algorithms are fun in academic exercises, but they're rarely used in practice, because of what you're seeing: too many recursive calls leads to excessive call stack usage, eventually terminating due to a stack overflow.

Short answer: try your code with a smaller data set.

Long answer: re-write your code to avoid recursion. You can use your own stack instead of the program's call stack.